# Internal server error of node js app after deployment to azure

Tags: azure, botframework, bots

I have created a sample bot,which is working in bot emulator and azure bot service with localhost url,but when i deployed to azure and hit its live url  it is giving internal error

```
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
```

and web config file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>

        <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </handlers>

      <rewrite>

        <rules>

            <rule name="DynamicContent">

                 <match url="/*" />

                 <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
            </rule>
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

live url of site

> https://hotel-reserve.azurewebsites.net/api/messages

Comment: Please include all necessary things in your question. No links to any websites please. That's not going to be helpful once your problem is fixed.

Comment: you have to go onto azure, advanced tools and into your logs.   you will be able to see the error files in there.   also if you go to site/iisnode folder.   you will be able to see all the console.log files

Comment: Can you please check logs from Azure tools and share the error?

Comment: @JyoFanidam...thanks but where can find the logs i gone through the logs tab but did n't find any usefull information ...and i am new to azure too...can you help where can find logs..